# What does Future() means in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, future

I'm new to NHibernate
the description for IEnumerable Future(); says the following

```
// Summary:
//     Get a enumerable that when enumerated will execute a batch of queries in
//     a single database roundtrip
```

Just wondering what does it means, the description has nothing to do with the word 'future'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Future allows to execute two or more sql in a single roundtrip, as long as the database supports it.

It's also almost transparent, so you'll want to use Futures whenever possible. If NHibernate can't execute the queries in a single roundtrip, it will execute the queries in two or more, as expected.

From http://ayende.com/blog/3979/nhibernate-futures

> Let us take a look at the following piece of code:

```
using (var s = sf.OpenSession())
using (var tx = s.BeginTransaction())
{
    var blogs = s.CreateCriteria<Blog>()
        .SetMaxResults(30)
        .List<Blog>();
    var countOfBlogs = s.CreateCriteria<Blog>()
        .SetProjection(Projections.Count(Projections.Id()))
        .UniqueResult<int>();

    Console.WriteLine("Number of blogs: {0}", countOfBlogs);
    foreach (var blog in blogs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(blog.Title);
    }

    tx.Commit();
}
```

> This code would generate two queries to the database
>   Two queries to the database is a expensive, we can see that it took us
>   114ms to get the data from the database. We can do better than that, let us 
>   tell NHibernate that it is free to do the optimization in any way that it likes

```
using (var s = sf.OpenSession())
using (var tx = s.BeginTransaction())
{
    var blogs = s.CreateCriteria<Blog>()
        .SetMaxResults(30)
        .Future<Blog>();
    var countOfBlogs = s.CreateCriteria<Blog>()
        .SetProjection(Projections.Count(Projections.Id()))
        .FutureValue<int>();

    Console.WriteLine("Number of blogs: {0}", countOfBlogs.Value);
    foreach (var blog in blogs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(blog.Title);
    }

    tx.Commit();
}
```

> Instead of going to the database twice, we only go once, with both
>   queries at once. The speed difference is quite dramatic, 80 ms instead
>   of 114 ms, so we saved about 30% of the total data access time and a
>   total of 34 ms.

Comment: Out of pure curiosity, which statement is actually triggering the call to the database? Is it just queuing all of the Future<T> statements up until `.Value` is called?

Comment: @TyCobb it will be triggered when any of the values are needed. In this case, `countOfBlogs.Value`. If this statement is removed, it will then execute when blogs starts iterating.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you use future, request the value, then use another future, it will execute in two queries anyway...